# restricting numbers to a percentage

Tags: javascript, numbers, percentage, restrict, forcing

I was thinking about forcing people to be only capable of writing the numbers between 0-100 (because of the maximum number attained via a percentage is 100%).

Is there a way to force people to input a number between 0-100%? I am already restricting them to 3 digits using javascript.

I am looking to using javascript for this.

Comment: Just parse it and check if it's in that range..

Comment: Can you post any code to show what you have tried?

Comment: `if (val <= 100 && val >= 0) {}`

Comment: @Jordan: I looked up what parse is, and I don't see the relevance, but I assume that I am not looking on the right sites. I usually would use things like parseInt or parseFloat. So, I'm not looking in the right place, am I?

Comment: @cfs, the code I had was pretty much the same as Ian.

Comment: @M.Sidim Could you post your code in your question? That will help us provide an answer for you.

Comment: @Ian, thank you. I meant on input itself. I just saw what Yann posted. I did not know that I could do this on input like this. I knew for js on validation, but not on input. However, I am grateful for your help :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [number input](http://html5doctor.com/html5-forms-input-types/#input-number) `<input type="number" min="0" max="100">`, but it won't work [in all browsers](http://caniuse.com/input-number) so you'll have to complement it by some javascript in order to double check the value is correct.

Comment: I did not know you could do that on input like that. This is awesome :) But yeah, you're right I'll still validate it afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Range type input element, which appears as a slider.

```
<input type="range" name="percentage" min="0" max="100">
```

Or you could run a validation function on the onchange or onkeyup events, that checks for a value more than 100.

```
<input type="text" name="percentage" onkeyup="validate(this);">

function validate(el){
    if(el.value > 100){
        el.value = 100;
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh my, I did not see your answer. Thank you posting.

I will definitely compare Yann's method and yours. It appears that yours might be just as interesting!

As for the validation, I am definitely going to run it :)

Comment: You're welcome! Perhaps consider voting up the answer which ended up suiting you best :)

Comment: Oh yes, I can do that now! I forgot I have a rep of 15+ now :D